# hh.mm.ss to seconds in c#

Tags: time, format, converters, data-conversion

Best way to convert a string of number (hh.mm.ss) to seconds? I use visual studio, so C#.

```
//I receive the data in this format hh.mm.ss and I store it in "time"

String time;

...

//hh.mm.ss to ss
time = time.Replace(".", "");

//how can I proceed?

int numTime = Int64.Parse(time);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can feed your string into a datetime object like so

```
string dateString = "24.12.03";
DateTime dateObject = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "hh.mm.ss",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Then you can simply pull the number of seconds like this

```
Console.WriteLine(dateObject.Seconds);
```

Comment: Seconds is not recognized. It is underline with red. Do I need to install nuget packages?

Comment: indeed i'm sorry it's dateObject.Second as the documentation shows : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx